# How to check and change a value in a Text file? (Python 2.7.11)

Tags: python

Text File explained:

```
Joe,Bloggs,J.bloggs@anemailaddress.com,01269512355, 1 ,0, 0, 0, 0
Fname, Lname, Email, number, Value i want checking  ^ , ...,...,...,...
```

Objective: The check that the number in value[4] of the key is not 0 or 7.
If it is 0 then it changes to 1, and if it is 7 then it changes to 6.
So if it's 0 then + 1, if it's 7 then -1.

Text file:

```
Joe,Bloggs,J.bloggs@anemailaddress.com,01269512355, 1,0, 0, 0, 0
Sarah,Brown,S.brown@anemailaddress.com,01866522555, 5,0, 0, 0, 0
Andrew,Smith,A.smith@anemailaddress.com,01899512785, 7,0, 0, 0, 0
Kevin,White,K.white@anemailaddress.com,01579122345, 0,0, 0, 0, 0
Samantha,Collins,S.collins@anemailaddress.com,04269916257, 0,0, 0, 0, 0
```

After the code has run, it should look like this:

```
Joe,Bloggs,J.bloggs@anemailaddress.com,01269512355, 1,0, 0, 0, 0
Sarah,Brown,S.brown@anemailaddress.com,01866522555, 5,0, 0, 0, 0
Andrew,Smith,A.smith@anemailaddress.com,01899512785, 6,0, 0, 0, 0
Kevin,White,K.white@anemailaddress.com,01579122345, 1,0, 0, 0, 0
Samantha,Collins,S.collins@anemailaddress.com,04269916257, 1,0, 0, 0, 0
```

The code i have so far produces an error:

```
fileinfo[j] = i[0] + ',' + i[1] + ',' + i[2] + ',' + i[3] + ',' + str(value) + ',' + i[5] + ',' + i[6] + ',' + i[7]+ ',' + i[8] + '\n'
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Code:

```
f = open ("players.txt","r")
fileinfo = f.readlines()
f.close()

j = 0
for i in fileinfo:
        i = i.strip()
        i = i.split(",")
        value = int(i[4])
        if value == "0":
                value = value + 1
        fileinfo[j] = i[0] + ',' + i[1] + ',' + i[2] + ',' + i[3] + ',' + str(value) + ',' + i[5] + ',' + i[6] + ',' + i[7]+ ',' + i[8] + '\n'
        j = j + 1

        if value == "7":
                value = value - 1
        fileinfo[j] = i[0] + ',' + i[1] + ',' + i[2] + ',' + i[3] + ',' + str(value) + ',' + i[5] + ',' + i[6] + ',' + i[7]+ ',' + i[8] + '\n'
        j = j + 1

f = open ("players.txt","w")
for i in fileinfo:
        f.write(i)
f.close()
```

This is probably a very complex way of doing what i want to do. Please can you help me with my objective. Feel free to rewrite my entire code, but can you explain in detail what you have done. I am quite new to coding.

For future readers

There are two answers that work. I can only tick one of them. Hope this question helps future readers as it has done me.

Comment: You want `','.join(i)` to create a string from a list deliminated by ",". Also you should have a look at the `enumerate` function to eliminate the need for `j`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems with your code are as follows:

1. You should remove the whitespace around the number before converting it to an int:
   `value = int(i[4])` would crash if there were whitespace around the number. Use `value = int(i[4].strip())` to fix this.
2. You're converting the value to an integer, then comparing that integer to a string. This will always evaluate to `False`.

   `value = int(i[4])
   if value == "0":`
3. You're incrementing `j` twice per loop, which is why your code crashes with an IndexError. I suggest using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of manually maintaining `j`.

The fixed code could look like this:

```
for j, i in enumerate(fileinfo):
    i = i.strip()
    i = i.split(",")
    value = i[4].strip()
    if value == "0":
        i[4] = "1"
    elif value == "7":
        i[4] = "6"
    fileinfo[j] = ','.join(i) + '\n'
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining why my code doesnt work. I have tried your code and it works perfectly. Thank you for the effort of helping me. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplified version of your code (Totally untested).

```
with open ("players.txt","r") as f:
    parts = [[y.strip() for y in x.split(",")] for x in f if x.strip()]

with open("players.txt", "w") as f:
    for part in parts:
        #So if it's 0 then + 1, if it's 7 then -1
        if part[4] == "0": part[4] = "1"
        elif part[4] == "7": part[4] = "6"
        print>>f, ",".join(part)
```

Comment: @Dot_Py: Only in python2 and as long as `f` is a file-like object.

Comment: Whoops, I dont have to do that.. Updating. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, i made a typo when entering the code. All sorted now haha. Thanks for you effort in helping me. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Toby: You might have an empty line that might cause it to break. Check the updated code.

Comment: You shouldn't have new files. The code reads from and writes to the same file. Clean up your environment and try again .. :)

Comment: Ive edited the previous post stating why im stupid haha

Answer (score 1):

You increment `j` twice each time through the loop, when it is supposed to track the position of each line, and thus it gets too big and causes the error.

Comment: Sorry but i dont quite get you. Should i remove or add a comma are you saying?

Comment: I had miscounted the components in each line; the real problem is with incrementing`j` twice each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a corrected version of your code (explanation below). I tried to make as little changes as possible.

```
f = open("players.txt","r")
fileinfo = f.readlines()
f.close()

for i in enumerate(fileinfo):
    i[1] = i[1].strip()
    i[1] = i[1].split(",")
    #Make sure we don't go out of range, if so, skip to the next line.
    if len(i[1]) < 5:
        continue
    value = int(i[1][4].strip())
    if value == 0:
        value += 1
    elif value == 7:
        value -= 1

    i[1][4] = str(value)
    fileinfo[i[0]] = ",".join(i)

f = open("players.txt","w")
f.write("\n".join(fileinfo))
f.close()
```

1. `value` is an int, but you were comparing it against strings.
2. `j` was not needed and I replaced it with the `enumerate` function. This will create pairs of [index,value] for you to use.
3. You were checking `value` twice and setting `i` twice. I corrected this by cleaning up the if blocks and utilizing `elif`.
4. The `.join` method saves you a lot of work. It creates a string from a list with a deliminator. `' '.join(['Hello', 'world!'])` becomes `Hello world!`.
5. If there are any lines which are too short, it would error (a blank line for example). I added a check which will skip that line in such a scenario by utilizing `continue`.
6. You should strip the whitespace around the element before attempting to convert to int.
7. When adding to a value, it's often easier to utilize `+=` and `-=`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [Scott Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37329563/966508) meant:

```
j = 0
for i in fileinfo:
    # Do something on fileinfo[j]
    j = j + 1

    # Do something on fileinfo[j]
    j = j + 1
```

Let's say you have three lines in `fileinfo`: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
On first loop iteration you have `i = 'aaa'` and `j = 0`. `fileinfo[0]` points to the first line.
On second iteration `i = 'bbb'` and `j = 2`. `fileinfo[2]` points to the third line.
On the third iteration `i = 'ccc'`and `j = 4`. You try to read the fifth line (`fileinfo[4]`) which does not exists.

Only increment the value of `j` once per loop iteration and `i`/`j` will stay in sync.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. It makes more sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hunter is write about you erroneously incrementing `j` twice in the loop. Also you would probably also want to write the whole thing a little more readable, such as:

```
filename = 'players.txt'

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

output = []

for line in lines:
    split_line = line.split(',')
    split_line = map(str.strip, split_line)

    num = split_line[4]

    if num == '0':
        split_line[4] = '1'
    if num == '7':
        split_line[4] = '6'

    output.append(','.join(split_line))

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(output))
```

assuming you dont care for whitespace between the commas.